# mod_wsgi-express service not stating

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to use mod_wsgi-express for a django project. This project will be served through the main instance of apache, with a proxy.  My purpose is to serve a python 3 application with a mod_wsgi for python 2 installed on the "main" apache server. (I've many apps on the same server)

I've created a systemd service which should launch the mod_wsgi-express instance, using my own service file :

https://gist.github.com/frague59/87529fc28b098dd116f09be92cf66af0

and

https://gist.github.com/frague59/8de1d03800042db95c82452af280dffe

I've to mention that those scripts works on another server, same distro, same version (debian oldstable)

... but the mod_wsgi-express does not start : no error message, no log...

I've noticed that a dir is created in tmp:

```
/tmp/mod_wsgi-127.0.0.1:8081:993
```

I've tried to start the apachectl from here:

# apachectl configtest

And I have a weird message:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 241 of /tmp/mod_wsgi-127.0.0.1:8081:993/httpd.conf:
Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition.
```

I posts the generated httpd.conf file for example:

https://gist.github.com/frague59/a6d8d26b704565b39f7352a7c16e07d3

Error seems to be around:

```
send-buffer-size=0 \
```

Comment: I've got it, the send-buffer-size value is guilty...

I've added the --send-buffer-size 1024 to the service StartExec command line, and the service starts !

Default value fails to start the server...

Comment: Not related, but for a permanent setup, you should use ``--server-root`` to specify a directory where files are generated. Don't rely on default under ``/tmp`` as some Linux systems can be configured to have cron jobs that delete old files under ``/tmp``, which can break things.

Comment: Also be aware that mod_wsgi-express does not require you to have the Apache service also running, unless you are using it as a front end proxy. If doing proxying, you should really read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html . and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/07/redirection-problems-when-proxying-to.html just ignore how it is talking about docker as still relevant.

Comment: To debug startup issues, use ``--log-to-terminal`` and ``--startup-log``, run from command line as root with arguments you want to use and post results. Better still, don't use ``start-server`` from init scripts, use ``setup-server`` to pre-generate files and then use ``apachectl start`` and ``apachectl stop``. See the PyPi page for mod_wsgi for details of using ``apachectl`` method.

Comment: Hi Graham, 

Thanks for the trick about the --server-root parameter ! I'm using the "main" apache as proxy, so it is relevant... The issue is really  about the send-buffer-size, so I've set it up in the .service file. I think the default value (0) breaks the service startup, may be you should set it to another value or fix the parameter analysis on module startup. (worked previously with mod_wsgi 4.5.15, on another server with same service settings) > github: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/216